# Spring - Last ID from database as default input value in JSP.. how?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm writing an application and I got some problems with displaying last ID from my database, I want in order to input field in JSP has a default value which will be last ID from database. I tried with some options like `value="id" or value "${patient.id}"`but it never worked. How should I do it properly? Here is a code:

RegistrationPatient.jsp:

```
<p style="font-size: 26">
        ID<input style="font-family: Century Gothic; font-size: 26"
            type="text" value="//LAST ROW FROM DB//" name="id" disabled="disabled" />
```

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/registration.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView registrationPatient(@ModelAttribute("patient") Patient patient){

    setAppContext();

    clinicService.getNextId(patient);

    ModelAndView reg = new ModelAndView("RegistrationPatient");
    return reg;

}
```

ClinicService:

```
     public String getNextId(Patient patient){
     ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new   ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("clinicconfig.xml");
      patientDAO = ctx.getBean("patientDAO", PatientDAOImpl.class);

      patient.setId(patient.getId());

      return patientDAO.getNextId(patient);

    }
```

PatientDAOImpl:

```
public String getNextId(Patient patient) {
    String query = "SELECT idpatient FROM virtualclinic.patient ORDER BY idpatient DESC LIMIT 1";
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try{
        con = dataSource.getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()){
            int PID;
            PID = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1));
            int nextPID = PID + 1;
            patient.setId(String.valueOf(nextPID));
        }
       return patient.getId();

    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: OK, so what if two people register a new patient at the same time? They will use the same ID. So that's not a good strategy. Don't submit any ID when registering a new patient. Use an auto-increment or get the next value from a sequence when actually inserting the new patient in the database.

Comment: Stop trying to reinvent the wheel.  Most databases will automatically assign an incrementing number to a column.  Try some learning.